# Can't apply styles to VSCode Webview using html file

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview

I am building a VSCode Webview and trying to apply some css.

The only success I have had is with the following method

```js
const webview = this._panel.webview;
const stylePathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/css/styles.css'));
const styleUri = webview.asWebviewUri(stylePathOnDisk);

webview.html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='${styleUri}'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
  `
```

But I'd like to have my html in a separate file, used like so

```js
const htmlPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/html/index.html'));
webview.html = fs.readFileSync(htmlPathOnDisk.path).toString();
```

However, I cannot use `${styleUri}` within that html file. Nor can I use `<link ref='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{styleUri}}>`, nor EVEN can I use `<style>` tags within the `<head>` tags (none of these apply the css.

The first two methods (in the above sentence) I understand I may be incorrectly implementing, but the *third* style I didn't expect to fail.

Any advice?

Comment: When you load the html from disk instead of using a template string, you need to replace `${styleUri}` yourself. Try calling calling `fileContent.replace('${styleUri}', styleUri)`

Comment: Great solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As told by @Matt Bierner, here is the solution.

```js
const htmlPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/html/index.html'));
var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlPathOnDisk.path).toString();

const stylePathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this._extensionPath, '/res/css/styles.css'));
const styleUri = webview.asWebviewUri(stylePathOnDisk);
html = html.replace('${styleUri}', styleUri.toString());

// continue for any other resources, e.g. scripts

webview.html = html
```